# Load HTML content on webview inside Tableview cell taking too much time?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I am working on loading html contents on tableview cell so i have used webview for each cell. now i am facing an issue If the html content is heavy (i.e It's content multiple images and iframe or both) so  webview is taking time to get height of the specific content. I have tried following thing to overcome this issue. like.
1). First of all getting data from api's and load on webview and set height of webview after call `webViewDidFinishLoad` and reload tableview so it's causes flicker and if the content is heavy than not able to getting proper height.So I am searching for the best way to handle webview height inside tableview .

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have webview in each cell or just one cell have `UIWebView`?

Comment: yes i have a webview in each cell

Comment: Hey @jay mayu have you Any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `reloadData` but instead do (assuming your table has one section):

```
self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .automatic)
```

This should prevent the flickering.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response 
i have tried both ways reloadSections and reloadData but still getting same issue. because some time html content is too heavy and it's taking too much time to load so causes issue